# Bootstrap dropdown align right fail

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to allign my dropdown to the right part of navbar but failed, I have tried a lot of way to do it, in all ways I have failed.
If there is any way to fix this someone help me please, thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$curdir = getcwd ();
chdir('/forum');
require_once('/global.php');
chdir ($curdir);
$username=$vbulletin->userinfo['username'];
?>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="/index.php"></p>Name</p></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
              <li>
                                <a href='/index.php'><img src="/home.png" height="25" width="25"> Home</b></a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href='/forum'><img src="/forum.png"> Forum</a>
                            </li>
                             <li class='dropdown'>
                                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><img src="P.png"> Players<b class='caret'></b>

                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="action.php"><img src="/action.php"> Action</a>
                                    </li>                                 
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <?php if ($vbulletin->userinfo['usergroupid'] == '1' )
                            echo "
                            <li class='dropdown'>
                                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><i class='icon-user icon-white'></i> Welcome Guest<b class='caret'></b>
                                </a>
                                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href='#'><img src='/img/connectserver.png'> Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href='/login.php'><i class='icon-ban-circle'></i> Login</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href='register.php'><i class='icon-ok'></i> Register</a>
                                    </li>
                                </li>
                                </ul>
                                </ul>
                            </li>";?>
                            <?if ($vbulletin->userinfo['usergroupid'] != '1' )
                            echo "
                        </li>
                            <li class='dropdown'>
                                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle class='nav pull-right' data-toggle='dropdown'><img src='/img/connectserver.png'></i> Welcome <font color='red'>$username</font><b class='caret'></b>
                                </a>
                                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href='#'><img src='/img/connect.png' height='19' width='19'> Connect to server</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <!-- <li>
                                        <a href='#'><img src='/log-out.png' height='19'  width='19'> Log out</a>

                                    </li>  -->  
                                </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li></p>";?>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have two dropdowns, you want to align both to the right?

Comment: Give the `.dropdown-menu` a style of `left: auto; right: 0;`

Comment: show us the complete navbar markup or the context where you're using this dropdowns

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/bh47g/

Comment: @Ian: I want to pull to right only 1 dropdown, which will be shown for guests/or registred members.
P.S: I uploaded all navbar code

Comment: @Hoss Well then give it an `id`, and use that `id` in CSS to apply the style I provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html looks invalid. I cannot see all your code but it seems you have a closing li tag after your closing ul tag inside a p tag? li's can only be inside ul or ol tags. Make sure the html is correct and the try again! Hope this helps!

Comment: Last <li> closes "<li class='dropdown'>"

Comment: but </li></p> is invalid. should be something like: </li></ul>

Comment: A quick ctrl+f <p> will show that @SirKettle is on to something, as there is no found matches of the opening <p> tag in your code, while ctrl+f </p> finds 3 matches! somethings wrong here

Comment: @underbar I have fixed unless </p> tags but nothing changed. pull-right is not helping neither